# Angular 5 Trouble Loading childComponent from Parent

Tags: angular, angular5, angular-components, angular-component-router

I am trying to load a internal component :

app/stores/store/store-top.component

Once the user clicks on any of the stores from the list I wish to show the store-top content in store component.

Please provide some inputs

Below is my repository: https://github.com/kamleshkatpara/ngModuleIssue.git

Comment: The question needs to contain the relevant code directly. Linking to an external resource is not enough.

Comment: @Günter Zöchbauer, there are lots of files, I tried to make it easier for people to view and read my code

Comment: The probability that anyone is interrested in looking at a lot of files is *very* close to zero. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example, https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve. If you want an answer it would be helpful if you follow this advice. You can't skip doing your homework before asking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@Günter Zöchbauer

I fixed the issue, I was not loading the components inside my modules properly now it is working

Here is the demo link : https://github.com/kamleshkatpara/work.git